# javascript/jquery selecting last element in row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using "float: left" to place blocks in container. Like this on large screen:

[image]

on small scree:

[image]

can i select last element on row when user clicks on any element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the elements are all inline or floating then there wont be a concept of a `"last element on row"`.

I suggest you calculate the element using known values:

```
$('.box').on('click', function (e) {
  // calculate how many boxes will be in a "row" 
  var windowWidth = $('ul').width();
  var boxWidth = $('.box').outerWidth();
  var boxesPerRow = ~~(windowWidth / boxWidth);

  // get the index of the clicked element
  var index = $(e.currentTarget).index();
  // get the column of the clicked element
  var col = (index % boxesPerRow) + 1;
  // calculate how far it is to the end of this row, 
  // and select that element
  var $endOfRow = $('.box').eq(index + boxesPerRow - col);
  if (!$endOfRow.length) $endOfRow = $('.box').last();

});
```

Updated my answer with one that works. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gvbw9Lkz/4/

Comment: @Batbayar no problem. I improved the algorithm a bit.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can dynamically work out which elements are in the same row by comparing their [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) values:

```js
$(function() {
  // cache the collection of all the blocks
  var blocks = $('.block');

  blocks.on('click', function() {
    blocks.removeClass('highlight');

    var $this = $(this);
    // get the y coordinate of the clicked block
    var y = $this.position().top;

    // store the blocks in the row
    var rowBlocks = $this;

    // search backwards until we find a different y coordinate or reach 0
    for (var i = $this.index() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var block = blocks.eq(i);
      if (block.position().top == y) {
        // add the element to the rowBlocks selector
        rowBlocks = rowBlocks.add(block);
      } else {
        // different coordinate, stop searching
        break;
      }
    }

    // search forwards until we find a different y coordinate or reach the end
    for (var i = $this.index() + 1; i < blocks.length; i++) {
      var block = blocks.eq(i);
      if (block.position().top == y) {
        // add the element to the rowBlocks selector
        rowBlocks = rowBlocks.add(block);
      } else {
        // different coordinate, stop searching
        break;
      }
    }

    // hightlight the row
    rowBlocks.addClass('highlight');
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}
.block {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.block.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">4</div>
  <div class="block">5</div>
  <div class="block">6</div>
  <div class="block">7</div>
  <div class="block">8</div>
  <div class="block">9</div>
  <div class="block">10</div>
  <div class="block">11</div>
  <div class="block">12</div>
  <div class="block">13</div>
  <div class="block">14</div>
  <div class="block">15</div>
  <div class="block">16</div>
  <div class="block">17</div>
  <div class="block">18</div>
  <div class="block">19</div>
  <div class="block">20</div>
</div>
```